# @Valid annotation is not working in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

Here is the scenario, a controller annotated with `@RestController` and a `PUT` method whose `@RequestBody` argument needs to be validated. I use `@Valid` annotation on the argument and `@NotNull`,`@Min` annotations on bean fields, but they are not working.

Code is here:

the Bean:

```
public class PurchaseWrapper {
  @DecimalMin(value = "0.00",message = "discount must be positive")
  @NotNull
  private BigDecimal discount;
  @NotNull
  private Long merchandiseId;
  @NotNull
  private Long addressId;
  @Min(1)
  @NotNull
  private Integer count;
}
```

the Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("merchandises")
public class MerchandiseController {

@RequestMapping(value = "purchase",method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<RestEntity> purchase(@Valid @Validated @RequestBody PurchaseWrapper purchaseWrapper,
                                           @RequestParam String token){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(merchandiseService.purchase(purchaseWrapper,token),HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Autowired
PurchaseWrapperValidator purchaseWrapperValidator;

@InitBinder(value = "purchaseWrapper")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(purchaseWrapperValidator);
}
}
```

The pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have no idea what's wrong here... And I guess it's the problem that I use `@Valid` and `@Validated` annotations both on the same argument. But even though I omit the `@Validated` annotation, the `@Valid` is still not working...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out... it's because the `PurchaseWrapperValidator` which implements `org.springframework.validation.Validator` overrides the default `javax.validation.*` annotations.

Comment: reminders for myself .. you should use `binder.**addValidators**(new PurchaseWrapperValidator());`

Answer (score 2):

Put a dependency at pom.xml. Or, at start.spring.io select Validation on dependencies.

dependency:
groupId org.springframework.boot groupId
artifactId   spring-boot-starter-validation   artifactId

Comment: Adding in that dependency (spring-boot-starter-validation) worked for me.